# Is it safe to assume that in Landscape mode, height is always less than width?

Tags: android, graphics, scaling

I'm starting out on graphics for my Android game, the game is always in landscape mode. At the moment I am scaling my graphics by setting their width/height as some fraction of the window height. This way they are always the same proportion of the screen. It seems to be working well, but with I have done very limited testing. But is it dangerous to assume that while working in landscape mode, the window height will always be less than window width, and therefore making it the main constraining factor?

Comment: Why not just use SVG graphics using inkscape?

Comment: Won't I still need some metric to scale them from? But anyway, I am using libgdx with opengl so im not sure using svgs is an option

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a direct answer to your question; but the Android API defines the following orientations:

`Orientation.LANDSCAPE`, `Orientation.PORTRAIT` and `Orientation.SQUARE`.

Judging by these, I would assume that in landscape orientation, the window height will be less than window width. If the width were lower, it would amount to Portrait orientation, and if the width and height are equal, it should be treated as Square.

Having said that, you specifically ask about *window* dimensions; while I believe orientation is based on *screen* dimensions. So, I may be totally off track here!

Answer (score 0):

Your safest bet is to have a setting for this. There are some non phone devices with android that have square screens or are landscape by default.
Just decide your target audience before anything. There's no such thing as a "universal" app.